# Angular2-6, regexp and input decorator

Tags: regex, angular6

I have a component, which has `@input()` decorator. So, I am trying set regular expression in it.
Something like

```
<component [regex]="/^\d+$/" ></component>
```

or

```
<component [regex]="new RegExp('ab+c')" ></component>
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Try `<component [regex]="^[0-9]+$" ></component>`. Please add the real regex you want to use to the question.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token ^ at column 1 in [^[0-9]+$] in ng:///AppModule/InputComponent.html@151:57 ("<div class="form">
    <div class="f-row">
      <iw-input-masked class="iw-input-masked-container" [ERROR ->][regex]="^[0-9]+$"></iw-input-masked>
    </div>
  </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the RegEx as a string value, like

```
<component [regex]="'^\d+$'"></component>
```

or

```
<component regex="^\d+$"></component>
```

Then in your component you can use `new RegExp(this.regex);` to create the actual Regular Expression object